# Sort data based on key of a list of multiple dictionaries

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting, dictionary

I have a list like this

```
li = [
    {1: {'amount': 255, 'date': '25-02-2017'}},
    {2: {'amount': 25, 'date': '2-02-2017'}},
    {3: {'amount': 38, 'date': '20-02-2017'}},
]
```

I am trying to sort the data in ascending and descending order based on `'amount'`.

I tried the following but am unable to get the result I want:

```
import operator
li.sort(key=operator.itemgetter('amount'))
```

and

```
from operator import itemgetter
newlist = sorted(li, key=itemgetter('amount'))
```

Both raise an exception, `KeyError: 'amount'`.

Comment: That's because the list items are dicts of dicts

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a list of dictionaries with a single key, whose value is another dictionary. It is that **nested** dictionary that has the key `'amount'`.

You'd have to reach in and get that single value:

```
newlist = sorted(li, key=lambda d: d.values()[0]['amount'])
```

This only works in Python 2, where `d.values()` is a list. In Python 3 you'd have to use `next(iter(d.values())['amount']` instead.

You'd be much better of not producing the nested structure *at all*. Move those numbered keys into another key-value pair perhaps:

```
li = [
    {'id': 1', amount': 255, 'date': '25-02-2017'},
    {'id': 2, 'amount': 25, 'date': '2-02-2017'},
    {'id': 3, 'amount': 38, 'date': '20-02-2017'},
]
```

at which point your original attempt would work. You can transform your current data structure with `[dict(id=d.keys()[0], **d.values()[0]) for d in li]` but it'd be better to fix the code that produced the list.

Comment: so i am currently not reaching the second  dict

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code which uses lambdas,

```
li=[{1:{'amount':255,'date':'25-02-2017'}},{2:{'amount':25,'date':'2-02-2017'}},{3:{'amount':38,'date':'20-02-2017'}}] 
print(li)

li.sort(key=lambda x:list(x.values())[0]['amount']) # ascending
print(li)

li.sort(key=lambda x:list(x.values())[0]['amount'],reverse=True) # descending
print(li)
```